# Открытие страницы внутри Android-приложения

Tags: java, android, webview

В некоторых приложениях, web-страница из ссылки открывается не в браузере, а прямо внутри приложения. Подскажите, как называются элементы для такой реализации. В какую сторону копать?

Comment: Так у Вас третий тег в вопросе - WebView. Вот и ответ.

Comment: Копайте в сторону `WebView` и [Chrome Custom Tabs](https://segunfamisa.com/posts/chrome-custom-tabs).

Answer (score 2):

посмотрите в сторону WebView,

```
mWebView.loadUrl("http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android");
```

более подробно на русском можно прочитать здесь: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/mybrowser.php

Answer (score 0):

```
 WebView vw = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
 vw.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```